# Multiprocess web server with ocaml

Tags: web-services, ocaml, load-balancing, devops

I want to make webserver with ocaml. It will have REST interface and will have no dependencies (just searching in constant data loaded to RAM on process startup) and serve read only queries (which can be served from any node - result will be the same).

I love OCaml, however, I have one problem that it can only process using on thread at a time.

I think of scaling just by having nginx in front of it and load balance to multiple process instances running on different ports on the same server.

I don't think I'm the only one running into this issue, what would be the best tool to keep running few ocaml processes at a time and to ensure that if any of them crash they would be restarted and have different ports from each other (to load balance between them)?

I was thinking about standard linux service but I don't want to create like 4 hardcoded records and call `service start webserver1` on each of them.

Comment: what about https://blogs.janestreet.com/async-parallel/  ? (I personally never used it).

Comment: Looking into it, seems like it's addressing exact problem I need

Comment: Well, downside I see to this is serializing/deserializing structures for worker processes, thus, master process takes more overhead... In nginx loadbalancing way every process is independent and doesn't need to serialize anything (apart from http responses it returns), I'm now investigating http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a strong requirement for multiple operating system processes? Otherwise, it seems like you could just use something like [cohttp](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp) with either `lwt` or `async` to handle concurrent requests in the same OS process, using multiple threads (and an event-loop).

As you mentioned REST, you might be interested in [ocaml-webmachine](https://github.com/inhabitedtype/ocaml-webmachine/tree/master/examples) which is based on `cohttp` and comes with well-commented examples.

Comment: I don't think that would be multiple, native threads, one OCaml process can only take advantage of one CPU core at the time I believe?